# How to convert this string into DateTime in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

```
string = "02/27/2014 08:01:11"
DateTime.parse(string) # failed
```

and

```
DateTime.strptime(string) # failed
(string).to_datetime # failed
```

I also included these at the top:

```
require 'date'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/conversions'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Date::strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) method :

```
require 'date'

s =  "02/27/2014 08:01:11"
Date.strptime(s,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
# => #<Date: 2014-02-27 ((2456716j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```